Google Sheets Script new Date() with timezone is providing wrong time
When I run this code at 6pm in PST timezone (GMT-8), it gives me the correct date but 6am instead of 6pm.
  var nowvalue = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(nowvalue);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('ddd" "m"/"d" "hh:mm');

If I set it to GMT+4, it correctly gives me 6am the next day (e.g., 12 hours ahead of me)
If I set it to just GMT, it correctly gives me GMT time right now.
So confused!!

Link to the documentation of the API you were using.

Why the single-quote marks?

What part of your format do you believe specifies AM/PM indicator?

Get PST timezone
This issues could be possibly caused by Daylight Saving Time(DST) and parameters like "GMT-8" does not automatically adjust to adapt DST. You may use time zone identifier instead.
Sample Code
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var nowvalue = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(nowvalue);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('ddd" "m"/"d" "HH:mm');

}

Sample Output

References:
Using timezone identifiers

Totally fixed! Thank you so much!!!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
